# Custom Segue from UITableViewController remove top layout guide

Tags: ios, swift2, storyboard

When I try to add a custom segue from a UITableViewController this one remove my Top layout guide. That is a problem because it change my layout from a view to another. (See pictures below)

In my first picture with the custom segue I cannot have the Top layout guide.

[image]

In the second picture you can see the Top layout guide appear but I lost my segue.

[image]

Is there a way to force the Top layout guide to be present programmatically or by using the Storyboard ? I need the segue that be present to keep a generic code.

Thank you for the help

Comment: Have you actually built and run the app with the same results? What's shown in IB isn't necessarily accurate of what happens at runtime.

Comment: Between my first view and my second view the buttons at the top and the title moves a little lower. So the result is not the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check Simulated Metrics of your view controller 
[image]

If you want to force the top layout appeared in IB, change value of Status Bar to Default

However, as jjaatie said, what's shown in IB isn't real result when you compile and run the app